# Assigning a variable to each row from a Get query

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-blade

In my controller, I'm selecting all rows from a table, lets call it Users.

```
$users = User::get();
```

Let's say I want to assign a variable to each row from the Users table, that determines how old they were 10 years ago

I'm assuming I have to use a foreach

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $decadeAgo = $user->age - 10; 
}
```

Now in my blade, how can I display each user row, while also displaying the $decadeAgo variable?

Answer (score 1):

try this as [official laravel suggestion for blade templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates):

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>{{ $user->age - 10 }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the results and address each object by reference:

```
foreach ($users as &$user) {
    $user->decadeAgo = $user->age - 10; 
}
```

Then, in your blade template you will have access to the element you created on the $user object.

```
{{ $user->decadeAgo }}
```